# Facebook Registration : does not work with IE8

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to setup Facebook registration. 
It works for Chrome/Safari/Firefox but it does not work with IE8.

Here is the issue :

- go to https://preprod.cmesdonnees.com/facebookauth/registerwithfacebook
- log-in with your FB account (or a test account)
- type a password in "Mot de passe"
- just click on  "Inscription" (Register in FR)
- a Facebook disclaimer window opens, select "Continuer"
- on all browser, you'll be redirected to a success page
- on IE8 the window closes and nothing happens. This is my issue.

You can browse the page source code, I added the namespace to the html tag, played also with some HTTP Header, but it doesn't work.

Any help would be really appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver is probably not sending a P3P header, which IE likes to see so it can store the cookies it's receiving.   See http://www.admon.org/how-to-implement-p3p-http-headers-for-cross-site-cookies/ for more information on how to ensure you've got your p3p headers specified. (or if you're a windows guy, see http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfP3PAndACompactPrivacyPolicy.aspx)

Comment: Hi I copied the HTTP Response headers I found on the Facebook Demo page for Registration, but with no success. I added P3P, X-UA-Compatible, X-XSS-Protection... It does not work with IE8